# What would be the better way to remove attributes in the result data using lodash filter with predicate array of objects?

Tags: javascript, filtering, lodash

Working codepen [link](https://codepen.io/nagarajan_ceg/pen/abmEgbQ?editors=1111)

Sample data available:

```
var cr_data = [
  {
    timestamp: "2020-12-29T11:45:57-08:00",
    data: ["a", "b", "c"],
    local: false,
    source: true,
    x_obj: ["5a9b320a-c720-44d1-8f27-288533510f1f"],
    y_obj: "5e89a36f-de39-4552-af2b-8dd73feed692"
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-11-29T11:45:57-08:00",
    data: ["a", "b", "c"],
    local: true,
    source: false,
    x_obj: [
      "6a9b320a-c720-44d1-8f27-288533510f1f",
      "7a9b320a-c720-44d1-8f27-288533510f1f"
    ],
    y_obj: "6e89a36f-de39-4552-af2b-8dd73feed692"
  }
];
```

Available filter to apply on above data. filter_obj should match all the given attributes value need to be match with data provided:

```
var filter_obj = {
  local: true,
  x_obj: [
    "6a9b320a-c720-44d1-8f27-288533510f1f",
    "7a9b320a-c720-44d1-8f27-288533510f1f"
  ],
  y_obj: "6e89a36f-de39-4552-af2b-8dd73feed692"
};
```

Performing filter using lodash to filter the objects from data. One more condition is certain attributes need to be removed in filtered objects: In this example the result object shouldn't have *x_obj* and *y_obj*. Figure out way to do this kind of filtering.

```
var data = _.filter(cr_data, filter_obj);
var omittAttr = function (item) {
  return _.omit(item, ["x_obj", "y_obj"]);
};
data = _.map(data, omittAttr);
console.log(data);
```

Result data looks like:

```
[{
    timestamp: "2020-11-29T11:45:57-08:00",
    data: ["a", "b", "c"],
    local: true,
    source: false
}]
```

I have iterate over the object multiple times, one  iteration with _.filter & another one with _.map to remove attributes. It looks like it's not the effective way to do the filtering using lodash.

How to eliminate the multiple iteration and do it in more simpler way using lodash? It's not necessary to do this filter with lodash. Any simplistic javascript way is also fine.

All suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can think, the only improvement could be to get the resulting `data` in one line by using Javascript's `Array.map` method:

```js
var cr_data = [{
    timestamp: "2020-12-29T11:45:57-08:00",
    data: ["a", "b", "c"],
    local: false,
    source: true,
    x_obj: ["5a9b320a-c720-44d1-8f27-288533510f1f"],
    y_obj: "5e89a36f-de39-4552-af2b-8dd73feed692"
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2020-11-29T11:45:57-08:00",
    data: ["a", "b", "c"],
    local: true,
    source: false,
    x_obj: [
      "6a9b320a-c720-44d1-8f27-288533510f1f",
      "7a9b320a-c720-44d1-8f27-288533510f1f"
    ],
    y_obj: "6e89a36f-de39-4552-af2b-8dd73feed692"
  }
];

var filter_obj = {
  local: true,
  x_obj: [
    "6a9b320a-c720-44d1-8f27-288533510f1f",
    "7a9b320a-c720-44d1-8f27-288533510f1f"
  ],
  y_obj: "6e89a36f-de39-4552-af2b-8dd73feed692"
};

var data = _.filter(cr_data, filter_obj).map(function(el) {
  return {
    timestamp: el.timestamp,
    data: el.data,
    local: el.local,
    source: el.source
  }
});

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This reduces the number of iterations through your data to 1x, though I don'T know about performance, that needs to be tested

```js
const filter = (data, filter) => {
  return data.filter((obj) => {
    return Object.keys(filter).every((key) => obj[key] === filter[key]);
  });
}
```